# Google docs spread sheets

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I want to insert a new row to my spread sheet when a button is clicked, and copy all formulas to the added row from the row above.

Ex:

```
Column A                Column B

2                           2+1
3                           3+1
```

When a row is inserted between rows 2 and 3, the formula in column B should be automatically copied.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of my app that does that. In this case the copyTo on line 7 is copying one cell, but you can modify the range, or replicate the line to copy as many cells as you want

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sss=ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertRowAfter(1);  // insert a blank row, 
  rowIndex++; // to adjust for the new blank row
  // set up the new blank row
  // ... nominal code with validation
  sss.getRange(rowIndex, colIndex).copyTo(sss.getRange(rowIndex-1, colIndex));
```